# How to move a process which ppid is '1' to foreground on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: linux, centos

I wrote a c++ program which need lots of time to calculate, so I put it to background and set its ppid to '1'. Then I can logout and keep it running on the server.

Now I'm login to the server again, from 'top' I can see it's still running, I want to move the process to foreground then check the current output but don't know how to do it, I'm still a rookie to linux, really need your help.

The output is using '\r' to keep refresh in one line, show the rate of progress.

I tried 'jobs' and find nothing, out put is empty.

Comment: In the future you might want to consider just running such a process in `screen` or `tmux` which allows you to disconnect and reconnect again later

Comment: @EricRenouf That's really better, I could check the current output anytime login again. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do it, run it with `nohup`

```
nohup ./a.out > your_log_file.log &
```

whenever you login back to server just do `tail -f your_log_file.log`

Comment: That's a good solution! I have not used that yet because my output is using '\r' to keep flashing in one line, to output the current rate of progress. If wrote them to a file, that's could be huge data. But this way remind me, I could use 'tail -r' or use 'wc -l' to check the output file. Thank you !